# DigitOcean - laravel 8 deployment through Github (error 500)

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean

I deployed the laravel app to digitalocean:
but I don't understand why is it showing error 500??

[image]

I connected a github repo to deploy it to digitalocean.

1- I set the build commands to: composer install
2- environment variables are set: `APP_NAME`, `APP_URL`, `APP_KEY`, `DATABASE_URL`, `APP_DEBUG`

This is how the repo looks (private)
[image]

What seems to be the issue??

Answer (score 1):

I just did check the repo and it seems the vendors folder not there and your build steps look like a typo issue so please run below command

```
composer install
```

Still you face the issue then refer the laravel logs for that what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

you also dont have a .env file

maybe copy the .env.example to .env

perhaps follow the instructions on the laravel site for the version you are using.

in your question, you have spelt 'install' incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

turns out there were typos of lower and upper cases in controllers according to the laravel log.

I fixed them and now the site is running. It's weird that these typos didn't trigger erorrs locally..

Answer (score 0):

All You have to do is configure the  .env file if u have a .example.env edit the file to .env if u dont have it just try to create one or clone one from another project and do composer install but don't forget to generate a key with php artisan key:generate in the end